# How to disable KWallet in KDE 5.4 when KWallet Manager is always unresponsive?

Tags: opensuse, kde5, kwallet

I'm using Opensuse Leap, and had initially entered a password when prompted by KWallet for the first time. However, I don't want to keep entering a password everytime I want to connect to Wifi. If I try to open KWallet Manager, I get a frozen window which I need to force close, usually.

Is there a workaround, or a text-based (config-file) way to disable KWallet?

If I open kdewalletmanager by command line, I get

```
kwalletmanager(20095)/kdeui (Wallet): The kwalletd service has been disabled
```

I might have disabled it once before (I was able to open the settings menu once before), but I still keep getting a password prompt for the wallet when I log in and it tries to connect to WiFi.